# How to create a callback when an ansynchronous recursive method is completely ready

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, callback

I need a recursive function to happen asynchronously with a callback that happens after the recursion is completely finished. I simplified it to get rid of the irrelevant parts (here is the code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DgaBg/8/).

```js
tree = {
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 2
    },
    "d": {
        "e": {
            "f": {
                "g": 3
            },
            "h": 4,
            "i": 5
        },
        "j": {
            "k": 6,
            "l": 7
        },
        "m": 8,
        "n": 9
    },
    "o": {
        "p": 10
    },
    "q": 11
};

Watcher = function() { };

Watcher.prototype.startDoingAsyncStuff = function(node, callback) {
    var me = this,
        key;

    if(typeof node === "number") {
        console.log(node);
    } else {
        for(key in node) {
            if(node.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                (function(node) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        me.startDoingAsyncStuff(node, callback);
                    }, 500);
                }(node[key]));
            }
        }
    }
};

w = new Watcher();

w.startDoingAsyncStuff(tree, function() {
    console.log("callback 1");
});

w.startDoingAsyncStuff(tree["d"], function() {
    console.log("callback 2");
});
```

I need the callback provided to `Watcher.startDoingAsyncStuff` to execute after the recursion is finished, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

The complicating factor here is that using a simple counter is not possible, since `Watcher.startDoingAsyncStuff` should be able to be executed several times without waiting for previous calls to finish.

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery or a similar library?

Comment: I am, but would I think it is a bit overkill to add jquery, just to achieve this. How would you say I would do this with jQuery?

Comment: `$.Deferred` would be helpful here (though you could do it with creative timeouts). Something like creating a new $.Deferred before you start and giving it a timeout where it gets resolved if a flag hasn't been set within a given timeframe, 500 milliseconds or something (though that might be longer than you need). Each run of `startDoingAsyncStuff` would reset that flag so the $.Deferred stays unresolved. There is bound to be a better way with $.Deferreds than this, though, counting all recursive levels before you start and subtracting from the count, resolving the deferred at 0 or something.

Comment: I will look into the `$.deferred` object, but unfortunately I am not working in a browser environment, but in Node.js, so I will have to find/create similar functionality in a node module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, for sub-stuff, you want to provide a callback that just notifies the level above it that it's done.  At the higher level, you have a count of "done" messages you expect to receive, and once you get that number, you call the "real" callback.

I originally had a counter prototype that'd do this outside the function, but the actual functionality is so simple that i incorporated it into the function itself.

```
Watcher.prototype.startDoingAsyncStuff = function(node, callback) {
    var me = this,
        key,
        jobCount = 0;

    if (typeof node === "number") {
        console.log(node);
        // There's no sub-stuff to do, so we're done here
        callback();
    } else {
        for (key in node) {
            if (node.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                (function(node) {
                    ++jobCount;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // we create a sub-callback to decrement the counter
                        // and run the "real" callback when the counter is back
                        // to 0.
                        // This works as many times as needed, because jobCount
                        // is local and accessed via closure.
                        me.startDoingAsyncStuff(node, function() {
                            if (--jobCount == 0) callback();
                        });
                    }, 500);
                }(node[key]));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Without adding extra timeouts, one way would be to do a first pass of the tree without actually performing any of the main tasks, but instead counting the number of resursions. Assuming your tree isn't massive you should be able to do this syncronously without locking the browser.

Then do a second pass, and after performing each main asyncronous task increment another counter; when it matches the count from the first pass, you can fire the callback.

Comment: Well, I like your answer, but unfortunately this is not going to work in my case. The code I posted is just a mockup. In reality I am recursively walking a file tree with Node.js, so walking it once synchronously first and then asynchronously to perform the actual tasks would take about as long as just doing everyting synchronously.

Also: the tree is potentially very big (like the entire file tree of your C: drive on Windows)

Comment: OK, well in that case I can only think of something similar to timeouts as described by Jed above. You wouldn't need jQuery, just another timeout which checks to see if `startDoingAsyncStuff` has been called within a certain time period (bigger than the largest iteration would require). If it hasn't, your walker was finished.